# how to set angular modal custom height and width

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have found a way to change the width of a angular modal, how ever I can not figure out how to set the height I want. I need the modal to be 400px width, 400px height. also I need to reposition it so it is in the center of the screen. thanks
[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/VAOfAvW846mJGgIvq0DK?p=preview)

```
 $scope.NewJobModal = function () {

      var modalInstance = $modal.open({
          templateUrl: 'views/modals/NewJobModal.html',
          controller: 'NewJobModalInstanceCtrl',
          windowClass: 'large-Modal',
          resolve: {
              p: function () {
                  return $scope.p;
              }
          }
      });
  };

.large-Modal .modal-dialog{
width:30%;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two things:

1 - In the Plunkr you provided you're not attaching you .css file. Change the src to href.

2 - Then in your css file:

```
.large-Modal .modal-dialog{
  height: 400px;
  width:400px; 
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need the modal to have fixed height and width?

Comment: yes, client wants ever modal throughout the project the same size.

Comment: how would you set the size such that the modal's list content gets the scroller for any overflow content?  I want a dynamic modal thats max-height is that of the viewport (minus some padding).  Forked his plunker to show my issue http://plnkr.co/edit/P2qVTu?p=preview

Comment: @jusopi Set a max-height on your <ul> and overflow: scroll too.

Comment: @jusopi Example: ul { max-height: 100vh; overflow: scroll; }

Comment: I came up w/ this prior to seeing your solution... it uses javascript to dynamically render the content.  Very cludgy but might be useful for someone else http://plnkr.co/edit/nWTZsW?p=preview

Comment: @jusopi Not bad, and if it works for your particular use case, even better.

Comment: it works but yours works perfectly http://plnkr.co/edit/Sw7DVv?p=info I'd much rather let CSS do what it does and not mix responsibilities of the 2 techs.  Thanks so much for this fix Alan.

Comment: @jusopi No worries, let me know if there's anything else I can help with. VH is a great property. Do you need to support <IE9?

Comment: We're targeting only modern desktop browsers and only officially supporting Chrome/Firefox at the moment.  That may change but so far I'm safe.  According to http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units even IE9 has partial support... wow!